# How to make a control appear as a child of my custom component in the structure window?

Tags: delphi, components

I'm trying to create a component (based on TFlowPanel) to act as a container for other controls.
The component will be populated with controls (based on some properties) during design-time and runtime too.
At design-time I want the developer to populate the component and then write code to access the child controls of the component.

---

I have created a simple component based on TFlowPanel to test this.
I have created a TPanel in the Create method of my component and set its parent to Self (my component).
When I place my component on a form I see the TPanel inside the component but I don't see it as a child in the structure window.

If I place a TFlowPanel on the form and drop a TPanel on it, the TPanel correctly shows as a child in the structure window.

[Structure window with MyFlowPanel1 (my component) and FlowPanel1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwJTG.png)

---

```
type
  TMyFlowPanel = class(TFlowPanel)
  private
  ...

constructor TMyFlowPanel.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
var
  vPanel: TPanel;
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);

  Self.Height := 99;
  Self.BevelKind := TBevelKind.bkFlat;

  vPanel := TPanel.Create(Self);
  vPanel.Parent := Self;
  vPanel.Caption := '***';
  vPanel.Height := 33;
  vPanel.Align := TAlign.alTop;

end;
```

---

The DFM file of the simple test from the image:

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 326
  ClientWidth = 619
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object MyFlowPanel1: TMyFlowPanel
    Left = 24
    Top = 24
    Width = 185
    Height = 99
    BevelKind = bkFlat
    Caption = 'MyFlowPanel1'
    TabOrder = 0
  end
  object FlowPanel1: TFlowPanel
    Left = 24
    Top = 144
    Width = 185
    Height = 145
    Caption = 'FlowPanel1'
    TabOrder = 1
    object Panel1: TPanel
      Left = 1
      Top = 1
      Width = 185
      Height = 41
      Caption = 'Panel1'
      TabOrder = 0
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: You have basically created a composite control. That panel is part of your control and as such is not being seen by the IDE as a design-time control. Controls added to another control like a panel during design-time will be seen as child controls. You need something like `ControlStyle := ControlStyle + [csAcceptsControls]` to be set on your control. And then controls need to be added to your control in design-time. Have a look at `TPageControl` and how new tabsheets are added to it.

Comment: @BlurrySterk The thing is that the developer will ** not ** add controls by hand, the component must be populated with TPanels at design-time ** by the component itself **, (by setting the "Active" property "=True"), which will read a database to retrieve information.

Comment: Like I said; he should start to look at `TPageControl`. It can lead him to his answer. This type of question has been discussed before.